# How do I send users a calendar invite?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Users book appointments on my website. I want to send them a google calendar invite so that they can accept and have it in their calendar. How can I do that with node is and sendgrid?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Google notification"? I don't know if this is a specific technology, so a link would be great too.

Comment: I mean a calendar invite.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail automatically parses attached `.ics` files and suggests the users in the UI to add them to their calendars.
This means you need to build the [right `ics` attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149571/how-to-send-ics-calendar-invite-through-sendgrid-so-that-it-renders-in-email-cl) and use the following snippet to attach it to the email you are sending:

```js
const SendGrid = require("@sendgrid/mail");

  const attachment = {
    filename: 'invite.ics',
    name: 'invite.ics',
    content: Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'),
    disposition: 'attachment',
    contentId: uuid(),
    type: 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST',
  };

    await SendGrid.send({
      attachments: [attachment],
      templateId,
      from: {
        email: config.emailSender,
        name: config.emailName,
      },
      to: user.email,
      dynamicTemplateData: templateData
   });
```